# Javascript rectangle collision

Tags: javascript, geometry, collision-detection

I am working on 2D, non-rotated rectangle collision. I can detect it, and get the intersection width/height/position, but I am unable to "cancel" it. This is the "cancelling" code I have tried:

```
if (this.bounds.intersects(player.bounds)) {
    var intersection = this.bounds.intersection(player.bounds);
    if (player.bounds.bottomRight().x > this.position().x)
        player.position().subtract(intersection.width, 0);
    else if (player.position().x > this.position().x)
        player.position().add(intersection.width, 0);
    else if (player.bounds.bottomRight().y > this.position().y)
        player.position().subtract(0, intersection.height);
    else if (player.position().y > this.position().y)
        player.position().add(0, intersection.height);
}
```

(The intersects and intersection methods work)

"this" is a wall which the player should be unable to intersect.
This is the effect currently:
[image: collision]

The player is the red square, and the wall is the black square.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Without knowing what library you're using, it's difficult to suggest a reasonable fix. It appears that you're allowing the red square to update its coordinates *before* checking that the new coordinates are valid.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm using my own (it's mainly just for fun)

Comment: Are you updating positions based on events or based on a render loop (e.x. `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your functions intersects and intersection work but I suggest you separate updating the player based on `intersection.width < intersection.height` or not, something like

```
if (this.bounds.intersects(player.bounds)) {
    var intersection = this.bounds.intersection(player.bounds);
    if(intersection.width < intersection.height){
        if (player.bounds.bottomRight().x > this.position().x)
            player.position().subtract(intersection.width, 0);
        else if (player.position().x > this.position().x)
            player.position().add(intersection.width, 0);
    }else{
        if (player.bounds.bottomRight().y > this.position().y)
            player.position().subtract(0, intersection.height);
        else if (player.position().y > this.position().y)
            player.position().add(0, intersection.height);
    }
}
```

Depending on how far in you detect the collision this may work more or less well.